# Why error message in debug window: ask with identifier <decode: missing data> is not currently being simulated submit succeeded

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, simulation, background-process

Why am I getting this error message in the debug window when I go through the process of simulating expiration of a background task. I put a breakpoint at the line right after the call to submit, where the print statement that prints "submit succeeded" as you see below. I've looked at other posts at Apple Developer Forums and here on stack**overflow**. I have tried probably all the answers. I still don't have a solution. When I used Apple's sample ColorFeed Xcode project, it worked the first time as I recall, and then it stopped working. It doesn't work in my project and also in a separate project I created just to test simulating the expiration of a task I submit.

> Task with identifier <decode: missing data> is not currently being simulated

```
let request = BGProcessingTaskRequest(
    identifier: BGTaskIdentifiers.processingTaskIdentifier)
request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 3)
do {
    try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
    print("submit succeeded")
} catch {
    print("submit failed with catch error:\n\t\(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Here's what the debug window shows:

```
 e -l objc -- (void)[[BGTaskScheduler sharedScheduler] _simulateExpirationForTaskWithIdentifier:@"background.processing.task"]

2022-11-02 21:13:14.221109-0500 TrialBackgroundProcessingTask[13301:615495] Simulating expiration for task with identifier background.processing.task
2022-11-02 21:13:14.221675-0500 TrialBackgroundProcessingTask[13301:615495] Task with identifier <decode: missing data> is not currently being simulated
```